# How do I browse a web application as if it is hosted on server

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, iis, web-applications, iis-7.5

I just created a web application project in Visual Studio 2010. I want that when I type:

http://testsub.test.com

It should go to my local web application project. So I did a entry in my `hosts` file located at:

```
c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
```

But when I try to setup http://testsub.test.com in my Visual studio 2010 web application project's properties I get error. Attached is the screenshot for it:

[image]

What more changes do I need to make?

Comment: Do you have IIS installed, and why are you not just using localhost?

Comment: Yes. I have already tagged my question as iis7.5

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio thinks the directory it is publishing is a remote server (just like you wanted) and it is telling you the automatic creation of the virtual directory does not work. Create the virtual directory by hand in IIS and set it as a "Application" and it should work.

Comment: It doesn't work because http://testsub.test.com is http://localhost. I want it to go to my application. So http://testsub.test.com should go to http://localhost/MyWebApp.

Comment: You know that, and I know that, but does VS know that? it all depends on how it is checking for localhost in it's internal code. If it is checking for the name localhost it won't work, if it is looking for 127.0.0.1 than it should work and you need to check that IIS is set up correctly to accept requests to testsub.test.com.

Comment: Yes, VS knows that and I have solved my issue by myself. I went into IIS and in bindings just changed the hostname against port 80 and now it works. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can check -

1. you should have IIS installed.
2. Check if in IIS there should be a website created which points to the http://testsub.test.com. AFAIK, you need to have a static IP for the subdomain to be used for the website. The website settings are properly done. I mean, the subdomain is mapped correctly.
3. When you publish you webproject to IIS you must open the VS2010 as "run a administrator" option.